# Use a struct from a object?

Tags: c++

I started with working code (not written by me obviously), I saw them make a class object dataflash which made sense to me, but then after that they used:

```
 DataFlash::ID id;
```

Which is obviously  because they needed an object of that struct, but the fact they went back to the DataFlash class bugged me, not sure why, but I thought "No, no, you should be using the object we just made now" and promptly changed it to what I have below, which produces the following error:

```
error: invalid use of ‘struct main()::DataFlash::ID’
```

Well that's no fair, I'm basically doing the same thing to my eye, why is this invalid use?  Are structs (and nested classes I assume too) useless once they are in an object?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    class DataFlash
    {
    public:
        struct ID
        {
            uint8_t manufacturer;       /**< Manufacturer id **/
            uint8_t device[2];          /**< Device id **/
            uint8_t extendedInfoLength; /**< Extended device information**/
        };
    };

    DataFlash dataflash;
    dataflash.ID id;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ nested classes don't work like Java's inner classes. A nested type is just a type defined in the scope of other. Is not an object defined inside other, the inner having access to the outer.

Comment: Types and values are very different things in C++.

Comment: So ID is a type defined inside DataFlash type (In its scope). So to use it, use the scope resolution operator: DataFlash::ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code defines several layers of nested scope, the original code is doing scope resolution with the scope resolution operator `::`

Your example uses a member access operator `.` and the struct ID simply is not a member, it lives in the scope of your type, a type and value is not the same thing.

As a footnote, enumerations can be accessed in both ways due to enum's scoping rules.

```
#include <iostream>

struct object {
   enum identifier {
      a = 2,
      b = 16,
   };

   identifier id;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   object obj;

   std::cout << object::a << std::endl;
   std::cout << obj.b << std::endl;
}
```